# /bin/ld: leetcode.c:(.text+0xfd): undefined reference to `fmax'

Tags: c, g++

I'm have some question about my code.

```
    int nums[9] = {-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4};
    int numsSize = 9;
    if(numsSize == 1) return nums[0];
    int *dp = malloc(sizeof(int)*numsSize);
    dp[0] = nums[0];
    int max = nums[0];
     for(int i = 1; i < numsSize; i++){
        dp[i] = fmax(dp[i-1] + nums[i], nums[i]);
        max = fmax(max, dp[i]);
    }
    printf("%d " , max);
```

after running :
VSC will show

'''
/bin/ld: /tmp/ccRLkQJO.o: in function `main':
leetcode.c:(.text+0xbf): undefined reference to`fmax'
/bin/ld: leetcode.c:(.text+0xfd): undefined reference to `fmax'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
'''

Comment: I have add  #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

Comment: `fmax` is from `<math.h>` and requires the math library. Link with `-lm`. (But since your code doesn't use any floating-point numbers, you might want to write your own logic here.)

Comment: sorry about that, but i'm beginner ,I'm not sure how to do.

Comment: How to link with the math library. `gcc/g++ {your usual stuff} -lm`. How to write your own max logic: `int max = a; if (b > max) max = b; if (c > max) max = c);`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `-lm` to your linker parameters.

I had the same problem while compiling glfw project.